# I have a problem with a function in matlab

Tags: windows, matlab

I'm depveloping a function in matlab, but I have the following problem.

When I assign the codigo variable to my function, matlab show me the next message

```
Error using ContLetrasTexto>shannon
Too many output arguments.

Error in ContLetrasTexto (line 111)
codigos = shannon(1, length(vectorprobabilidad), vectorprobabilidad, codigos);
```

My code is the following

```
% create the cell array of codes
codigos = cell(size(letra));
% call the recursive encoder function
codigos = shannon(1, length(vectorprobabilidad), vectorprobabilidad, codigos);

%Método shannon-Fano%
function shannon(inicio, fin, p, codes)

shannon_inicial = inicio;
shannon_final = fin;
suma_arriba = p(inicio);
suma_fin = p(fin);

while(shannon_inicial ~= shannon_final-1)
    if (suma_arriba > suma_fin)
        shannon_final = shannon_final - 1;
        suma_fin = suma_fin + p(shannon_final);
    else
        shannon_inicial = shannon_inicial + 1;
        suma_arriba = suma_arriba + p(shannon_inicial);
    end;
end;
for i = inicio:shannon_inicial
    p(i) = 0;
end;
for j = shannon_final:fin
    p(j) = 1;
end;
if(shannon_inicial-inicio+1 > 1)
      shannon(inicio,shannon_inicial,p,codes);
end;
if(fin-shannon_final+1 > 1)
      shannon(shannon_final,fin,p,codes);
end;

end
```

I'll be grateful for your help

Comment: Maybe you meant to define your function as `function p=shannon(inicio, fin, p, codes)`?

Comment: no, because y name the function already when I call it.

Comment: Add the `p=` to the line of code that starts with `function`, as I indicated above, and your error will disappear. Whether the code will be correct only you can tell, because your code sample is not complete. See [mcve] for how to make a question like this complete.